# Can we apply where clause in postgres Sql

Tags: postgresql, copy, psql

I am using the `\copy` command for migrating my data . But the table size is 30GB and it is taking hours to migrate. Can I use a `where` clause so that I can migrate only data that was available a month back?

```
\copy hotel_room_types  TO | (select hotel_room_types.*  from hotel_room_types limit 1) $liocation CSV DELIMITER ',';

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ...otel_room_types TO STDOUT (select hotel_room_types.*  from h...
```

Comment: Yes you can copy the results of a query. Note the `| ( query )` in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

Comment: can u give an example how to use that

Comment: `COPY (SELECT 1 a) TO '/tmp/one';`

Comment: The `COPY` command is an command the server handles. `\copy` is a `plsql` command thus a client thing. I took your "COPY" to be the first one.

Comment: Sorry i am using \copy of psql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a query with `psql`'s `\copy` just like you can with the SQL command `COPY`:

```
\copy (SELECT ... WHERE ...) TO 'filename'
```

After all, `\copy` just calls `COPY ... TO STDOUT` under the hood.